# Term for security checkpoints separated by sex

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, grammatical-gender

In some places, a security checkpoint has two areas, one for checking men, and another for checking women. I'm looking for the term which describes this segregation by sex. This would be the opposite of how "co-ed" is used for schools which allow students of both genders.

An example usage might be:

> Just inside the entrance, past the [multi-gender-word] security, sinks were placed for the washing of hands.

Comment: I think your definition, **security checkpoints separated by sex**, is the clearest. A possible variation could be "single sex security checkpoint" but I'm not terribly keen on that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there is a one-word antonym, but I would suggest:

> *sex-segregated* security checkpoints
>
> *gender-segregated* security checkpoints

Or if it's well understood in a given context to refer segregation by gender (as opposed to race) you could simply say:

> *segregated* security checkpoints

However, for the sake of clarity, in your example sentence you could simply say:

> Just inside the entrance, past the *male and female* security check points, sinks were placed for the washing of hands.

This should be sufficient to indicate that the are separate check points for men and women.

Comment: As much as I wanted something else, something more elegant to describe this, I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: If this is the correct answer for you, then you should explicity mark it as 'accepted', where shown, thus giving the answerer the benefit of the appropriate 'reputation points'.

Comment: I just get this image of the male security checkpoint winking at the female security checkpoint with a suggestive leer.

Comment: I planned on marking this as the correct answer, but was withholding the mark until I had seen more responses.

Answer (score 4):

I will recommend **"gender-specific"** as I think it sounds better than "gender-segregated" and clearer than simply "gendered".

Answer (score 1):

I would offer that the antonym of co-ed is ***same-sex***, as in this sentence:

> Other dorms are coed, with same-sex roommates, and same-sex bathrooms and floors or wings.
>   (*The College Buzz Book*, 2007)

So, I would refer to them as the *same-sex security checkpoints*.

Comment: When I think of *same-sex school* I think of a building with only students of one sex. Might *same-sex security checkpoints* imply a separate section or wing altogether? I'm only asking, as I do not know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: A same-sex school only admits students of the same sex (e.g., a woman's college). A same-sex dormitory would house only students of one sex. You can have a same-sex dormitory on a co-ed campus. You can find some examples of the term used [in this article](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2011/nov/29/dc-ruling-same-sex-dorms-not-discriminatory/print/). Same-sex security checkpoints need not be in a separate building, just like same-sex locker rooms would not necessarily be in a different building.

Comment: But same-sex dormitories would have to be on different floors albeit in the same building! Likewise I imagine the ladies/girls changing rooms and hence their same-sex locker room could not be adjacent to men/boys changing rooms but be, for example, at opposite ends of a corridor or hall.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, a _same-sex dorm_ is a building that houses either all male students, or all female students. A co-ed dorm has both male and female students, but a co-ed dorm may have _same-sex floors_, meaning, say, only women live on the odd-numbered floors, and only men live on the even-numbered floors. Put another way, you can have same-sex rooms in a co-ed dorm, but there is no way to have co-ed rooms in a same-sex dorm.

Comment: "You can have a same-sex dormitory on a co-ed campus." So to clarify, a same-sex dormitory is a separate building altogether but within a co-ed campus where both sexes can attend college. Thanks, I didn't know that! I was confusing dormitory with floor, I thought they were pretty much the same.

Comment: I think *dormitory* has different meanings in BrE & AmE. In BrE, it usually refers to a single *room* with multiple beds (probably 4+ beds) which would normally be single-sex. In AmE, I believe it generally refers to a *building* containing multiple units (rooms) of sleeping accommodation, with no connotation of how many people share each unit. I may be wrong but I think it could even include a building where each unit/room is for only one person. When I was at university (in Birmingham, England, in the late 1960's) we called these buildings "Halls of Residence", abbreviated to "Hall".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I appear to have omitted indicating that my comment above was a response to you! (I was tight on chars!)

Comment: Thanks @Trevor, you cleverly identified where my confusion stemmed from. Bravo!

Comment: @Trevor: Nice comment. Many if not most dorms in the U.S. are also called "Hall," but that alludes to the name of the building itself. In other words, one might say, "On our campus, Simon Hall is a dorm building, but Nelson Hall is where the math department resides."

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have slept and had breakfast, I thought about this more and decided that the word I'm looking for is an antonym of "unisex". I looked it up in the dictionary, and such a suitable antonym is "gendered".